# iOS swift change padding of my custom font in application

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, padding

I am working on custom font,IRANSansMobile_Bold. This font unwanted bottom padding. [can I change this bottom padding for entire application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owqKa.png) I have already use another font now it is not possible for me to add edgeInset in every control

Comment: Not sure if it's feasible for you, but when we had a similar issue our designer edited the font itself to fix the padding.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to edit the font ?

Comment: can I edit my custom font ? @totiG

Comment: Our designer said he used an app called Glyphs to edit the font: https://glyphsapp.com/